# The dropdown calculation in react to select the remaining tickets

Tags: reactjs

I have 4 seperate dropdown boxes. Consider if ticket value is 5 all boxes in selection should display 1-5 for selection.If I select 3 in anyone of the boxes the remaining boxes should display 1 or 2 in selection.If I select 2 in next box the remaining boxes should display 0 for selection But I don't know how to achive it.insted it display 5 for all dropdown for selection.How can I achive the solution.

```
import { useState } from "react";
const Example = () => {
  const [numTickets, setNumTickets] = useState(5);
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({
    adultNonVeg: "0",
    childNonVeg: "0",
    adultVeg: "0",
    childVeg: "0",
  });

  function handleChange(event, name) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    setSelectedValues({ ...selectedValues, [name]: value });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Number of tickets:
        <input
          type="number"
          value={numTickets}
          onChange={(event) => setNumTickets(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Adult Non-Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.adultNonVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "adultNonVeg")}
        >
          <option value="0">Select an option</option>
          {[...Array(numTickets)].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>
              {i + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Child Non-Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.childNonVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "childNonVeg")}
        >
          <option value="0">Select an option</option>
          {[...Array(numTickets)].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>
              {i + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Adult Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.adultVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "adultVeg")}
        >
          <option value="0">Select an option</option>
          {[...Array(numTickets)].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>
              {i + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Child Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.childVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "childVeg")}
        >
          <option value="0">Select an option</option>
          {[...Array(numTickets)].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>
              {i + 1}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Example;
```

Comment: it seems your code is incomplete, can you share more details and codes. or show what is the expected results ?

Comment: I have reposted the code